# How create a schedule query on BigQuery using only SQL like syntax?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, schedule

On Snowflake, is possible that using CREATE TASK clause, with the parameter SCHEDULE, like that:

```
CREATE TASK t1
  SCHEDULE = 'USING CRON 0 9-17 * * SUN America/Los_Angeles'
  USER_TASK_MANAGED_INITIAL_WAREHOUSE_SIZE = 'XSMALL'
AS
SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

Comment: Is important a DROP TASK like too, and maybe a CREATE OR REPLACE too.

Comment: Support for transaction will be a good plus in that command.

Answer (score 1):

SQL like syntax to schedule is not available yet and on same note if you want to, BigQuery provides ability to schedule query via cli.

see documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/scheduling-queries#set_up_scheduled_queries)

you can raise a feature request here ->

https://issuetracker.google.com/u/0/issues?q=status:open%20componentid:187149

Comment: The project use DBT.

Unfortunately, on BigQuery the lack of this feature is a problem, so i make an ugly workaround with terraform by now.

Comment: I open an ticket, and when they return i will replicate here. 

Thanks for the idea

https://issuetracker.google.com/u/0/issues/284084875